# Autowiring Spring beans in a super class extended by many subclasses

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Is there any downside to putting a ton of @Autowired beans in a super class which don't get used in that class but instead are used in the subclasses that extend the super class?

Comment: What do *you* consider a downside?  Do *you* see a downside?

Comment: Downside = Extra memory usage, speed degradation, etc.  And no, I don't really see any downsides when running currently - I'm just curious to see if anyone else has run into anything.

Comment: I would say there are no functional downside's, but some may not like a class that holds x members for the sole purpose of making them accessible to child classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no downsides.

Just make sure you don't use autowired constructors, because it will soon become a pain to support them.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will look ugly, the spring startup may take some milliseconds longer and of course this fields will need some more memory (the one that Java needs for the fields). But beside of this I will not expect any problems.

And for "normal" runtime there should be no impact (except the memory)

I think of lets say 10 to 30 fields of lets say up to 10 beans. If you have TONs of fields, than do a test and measure the memory and performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. If all your beans are singleton scoped it shouldn't be much of a problem, this is the "official party line".

If your beans are request scoped (like for instance a controller class), you may have a much bigger problem than you're aware of. Maybe some of those dependencies are also not singletons ? You can easily have 500 beans being constructed for every instantiation of a request scoped controller class, since you're building dependencies and their dependencies and so on.

Now since bean instantiation is slow as the glaciers in spring, you do have a problem. The official party line of the spring framework seems to be to ignore this problem, as I am sure @Bozho will vehemently defend in the comments of this response. All this is obviously because the "web scopes" were retro-mounted over the existing design in spring 2.0, and due to the huge amount of supported use-cases, this was done totally on the premises of the existing implementation.

The solution is, of course, to normalize your wired in dependencies; don't put them all in the base class. If you're lazy you can wire in an ApplicationContext and use explicit calls to getBean for each service when it's needed. This is, of course, totally contrary to any design guidelines for spring.